# Migrating to Cedar on Heroku and losing URL from heroku.com to herokuapp.com

Tags: post, heroku, cedar

I'm in the process of doing several major improvements to my main production app on Heroku

This includes : using PostgreSQL in development, upgrading to the latest Rails, move to a dedicated database with Crane, and using thin as a webserver. The "last" thing I wanted to do as a logical step was to upgrade my app to Cedar stack instead of Bamboo. I've followed most of the instructions and have an ok "clone" app.

I'd like to move forward and use this new cedar app instead of the bamboo one.

The problem is that this app main use is as a backend serving API requests to an iOS app. These requests are in the format : xxx.heroku.com/...

It was probably a bad idea to use this url in the first place, but this is it and can't be changed on all our current iOS users.

I can find a way to rename my cedar app xxx. The problem is that it will be xxx.herokuapp.com . I know there is an automatic redirect on heroku, but it seems to be only for GET requests. So all my API requests won't return the XML responses I need for the iOS app.

Any suggestions ? I thought I would be able to use xxx.heroku.app going forward and I'm a bit stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing is to replace your bamboo app with a simple app that redirects requests to your new URL.

I would suggest never using the heroku domains as production domains - always put your own domain in front of them.

Comment: But will it be able to redirect POST requests with parameters ? Seems more complicated than GET redirects